# How to utilize receive spacial beamforming to allocate beams to different transmitter?

Tags: communication, beamforming

Assume there are 2 Base Stations (BSs) each is equipped with \$M\$ antennas serving 1 User Terminal (UT) simultaneously. Say if the UT has 4\$\times\$4 Uniform Planar antenna array, which means it can generate 16 beams to receive the signal from the 2 BSs.

If I want to allocate \$n\$ beams to BS1 and the rest \$16-n\$ beams to BS2, based on the SINR maximization. First, the received signal at the UT can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf{y} = \sum_{b=1}^{2}\mathbf{H}_b \mathbf{x}_b+\mathbf{n} \in\mathbb{C}^{16\times 1} 
$$
where \$\mathbf{H}_b\in\mathbb{C}^{16\times M}\$ is the channel from \$b\$-th BS to the UT, and \$\mathbf{x}_b\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times 1}\$ is the transmit signal of \$b\$-th BS.

The spacial beamformer to UT1 can be set as \$\mathbf{U}_1\in\mathbb{C}^{16\times n}\$, and \$\mathbf{U}_1^H\mathbf{y}\$ results the dimension \$n\times 1\$. Does the \$n\$ in the dimension represent the \$n\$ beams? However, \$n\$ seems to represent the number of data streams.

I'm confused that how to use spacial beamformer at UT side to allocate \$n\$ beams to BS1 and the rest \$16-n\$ beams to BS2 for example based on SINR maximization.

Comment: Does " I want to allocate  beams to BS1 and the rest 16− beams to BS2" answer your question? Are you just confusing or duplicating terms?

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for your reply. The goal is to allocate the beams, but what I'm confused is that the dimension n seems to represent the number of data streams not the number of beams.

Comment: @SolarMike Also, I'm not very clear about the relationship between the number of beams and the number of data streams. Do I use the receive beamformer in a wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the question mention data streams? It clearly says 16 beams though.

Comment: Yes, but the estimated signal is the data stream, right? The estimated signal refers to the signal results from the received signal passing through the receiver (receiver beamformer).

Comment: @ZYX it's not a data stream, but as-orthogonalized-as-possible channel outputs, if you will; "data" happens after demapping and decoding. But that's just nitpicking the terminology here, and your MIMO book might use it that way!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "I want to allocate $x$ beams to one communication partner". The number of beams you can use is defined by your physical environment; you can only get as many independent channels after beamforming as you have uncorrelated paths in your signal's propagation; that's the thing about the rank of the channel matrices! Having 16 channels between a single UE and a BS seems a bit physically unlikely, unless you're actually doing mmWave (as in: 60 GHz), and even then, you probably are pretty limited in independent channels.

Comment: Of course, if you have one very good-SINR path between your UE and the BS, then that single path (and thus, that single channel after beamforming) has a high capacity. But that's, again, a question of the physical scenario, not something your receiver or your transmitter get to choose.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Thanks! I realized that I can not allocate the receiver beams to different BSs. But if I want to design a receive beamformer based on the maximum SINR. How can I deal with the dimension of the receive beamformer? Because I can not decide how many beams at receiver should be used to receive signal from BS1 or BS2.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You mentioned that the beamformer output is not data streams, but take the MMSE receiver as an example, the output of the MMSE receiver are actually data streams, right? My understanding is that even though both the MMSE receiver and the receive spacial beamformer are matrices and the expression are the same (matrix \$\times\$ received signal), they are not the same things. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: *How can I deal with the dimension of the receive beamformer?* you do your matrix decomposition, or whatever you do as "beamforming", and look at how many significant Eigenvalues (or whatever measure for SINR you get) you have. That gives your dimension. Again, you have zero influence over the channel.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are data streams, still. "Data" for me is bits. What you get, at best, are unsynchronized, pulse-shaped, noisy, symbol streams; i.e. channel output signals.

Comment: Thanks! I will think it more.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not familiar with beamforming but I guess the way to approach this would be to somehow find your most orthogonal solutions that *only involve one base station each*?

Comment: @user253751 good angle, so that's potentially even fewer. So, beamforming really is just a "geometric interpretation" of a matrix decomposition. Imagine your BS sends a symbol, i.e., a complex number \$x\$. Each of your UE's 16 antennas gets a differently rotated (i.e., phase-shifted), and attenuated \$y_k\$. I.e., it sees a 16-element vector \$\mathbf y\$, which can be computed from the one complex number that the BS sent, multiplied with a vector \$\mathbf h\$ consisting of the complex factors between \$x\$ and the elements of \$y\$. Now, the BS doesn't only have 1 antenna with which it …

Comment: … sends single complex symbol, it has \$M\$ of these, so it sends \$M\$ symbols in parallel, each from a different antenna, giving the transmit vector \$\mathbf x\$. Of course, all these symbols end up at all receive antennas, interfering with each other. You can't receive much info  that way.The mapping between that \$\mathbf x\$ and the received vector \$\mathbf y\$ is the channel matrix \$\mathbf H\$. Now, we can find a base transform to multiply with the "output" of \$\mathbf H\$ such that we get separable "channels" back. Of course, that only works when there *are* separable channels –

Comment: speaking in terms of *how* you find that base transform matrix, namely by doing a singular value decomposition, how many different singular values \$\mathbf H\$ has. If, for example, two receive antennas are at an angle that the reception of one is really just a complex multiple of the other, you lose rank in \$\mathbf H\$ (because two rows are linearly dependent). No chance to get a separable channel there! $$\,$$ "Beamforming" is just the interpretation of that base transform matrix you apply: you look at it and realize it consists of the complex vector you multiply with each receive …

Comment: … antenna signal. Now, that means that for one row of the base transform, waves that come from a certain direction add up constructively when observed to the complexly-weighted antenna array, and from others it adds up destructively. In case you get something like a straight path, that is the same as a beam!